# Access DLookUp returning Null

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've been looking all over and can't seem to find an answer. I have followed examples of other sample codes found online but nothing is working. 
I am trying to get a string of comments from a specific cell in my database query into a textbox of a form in the same database. I have been getting Error 13 mismatch error and 96? null error. Below is my code:

```
Private Sub Text757_Click()

    Dim Remarks757 As String

    If IsNull(DLookup("Remarks", "QueryDataPaveAll", "[YrRated] = Forms![FormDataEntryPave]![TextYrRated]" And "[RdSecNo] = Forms![FormDataEntryPave]![TextRdSecNo]")) Then
        MsgBox "No Record Found"

    Else
        Remarks757 = DLookup("Remarks", "QueryDataPaveAll", "[YrRated] = Forms![FormDataEntryPave]![TextYrRated]" And "[RdSecNo] = Forms![FormDataEntryPave]![TextRdSecNo]")
    Me.Text757 = Remarks757
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Remarks757` should be `Variant`, not `String`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a return value of `Null` from when it fails to find anything cannot be stored as a `String`, so you instead have to declare `Remarks757` as a `Variant`

```
Private Sub Text757_Click()

    Dim Remarks757 As Variant
    Remarks757 = DLookup("Remarks", "QueryDataPaveAll", "[YrRated] = Forms![FormDataEntryPave]![TextYrRated]" And "[RdSecNo] = Forms![FormDataEntryPave]![TextRdSecNo]")

    If IsNull(Remarks757) Then
        MsgBox "No Record Found"
    Else
        Me.Text757 = Remarks757
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. 
Unfortunately, I am still receiving error 13 with regards to my DLookUp function.

Comment: @RenMcD I don't really have experience with the `DLookup` function - how is the `And` in your query supposed to work?

Comment: The 'And' is used to look up both criteria not just one. In this case the criteria is both the YrRated and RdSecNo. 
If you are not familiar with DLookUp do you have another suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The VBA `And` operator works with numeric expressions, such as these examples from the Immediate window ...

```vba
? True And True
True
? True And  False
False
? 1 And 2
 0 
? 1 And 3
 1
```

But asking `And` to operate on strings triggers error #13: *"Type mismatch"* ...

```vba
? "foo" And "bar"
```

Now look at the 3rd argument you're submitting to `DLookup` ...

```vba
"[YrRated] = Forms![FormDataEntryPave]![TextYrRated]" And "[RdSecNo] = Forms![FormDataEntryPave]![TextRdSecNo]"
```

That amounts to one string `And` another string, which triggers the type mismatch.  Eliminate the error by making it all one string ...

```vba
"[YrRated] = Forms![FormDataEntryPave]![TextYrRated] And [RdSecNo] = Forms![FormDataEntryPave]![TextRdSecNo]"
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you. 
Unfortunately, it still returns type mismatch. The YrRated and RdSecNo should provide integers in the form. Have I made a syntax error?

Comment: Where?  Is it at `Remarks757 = DLookup(...`?  Is `Remarks757` still String or did you change it to Variant as Marcucciboy2 suggested?

Comment: Find out what `DLookup` is returning when you get the mismatch error.  Go to the Immediate window (Ctrl+g will take you there), paste in this highlighted text and press Enter: `Debug.Print DLookup("Remarks", "QueryDataPaveAll", "[YrRated] = Forms![FormDataEntryPave]![TextYrRated] And [RdSecNo] = Forms![FormDataEntryPave]![TextRdSecNo]")`

Comment: I changed it to variant because of a previous comment stating that if it returns null then it could not be stored as a string.
It returns Null

Comment: The return value is Null

Comment: Wait. What? You said the `DLookup` expression returns Null in the Immediate window.  In your VBA code, you assign the `DLookup` return value to a Variant variable.  I don't see how that can trigger a mismatch ... unless the `DLookup` expression in your VBA code does not match the one you tested in the Immediate window or unless `Remarks757` is not Variant.

Comment: I don't understand it either but it is working right now. Thank you for all your time and help!!